# Filter by array of objects using values pair

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have array of objects

```
var array = [
 {id: true, category: "cat1", name: "test1"},
 {id: true, category: "cat2", name: "test2"},
 {id: true, category: "cat3", name: "test3"},
 {id: true, category: "cat4", name: "test4"},
 {id: true, category: "cat5", name: "test5"}
]
```

How can i filter it if there is matching values of an array?

Here is my script :

```
let filtered = this.array.filter((array) => {
    return array.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
});

var category = [];

if(category.includes("All")) {
   return filtered;
} else {
   return filtered.filter((array) => {
     var keys = Object.keys(array);
     var matchFilter = false;
     category.forEach((key) => {
       if(array[key] === true) {
         matchFilter = true;
       }
     });
     return matchFilter;
   });
}
```

Then I have a checkbox on Front end to store the values for the variable `category`

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="All">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="5">
```

For now it just return me if the checked value has match the ID of my array of objects. My expected output is to filter it also by the value of category or name.

Comment: what contains `filtered` ?

Comment: It's a filter function for searching.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62986665/edit) when adding more information

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: There's just not enough information here. How / when does `category` get any values? What is `product`? It's not clear what the result should be from selecting any of your checkboxes

Comment: Is it multiselect?

Comment: just edited the question sorry, and yes it is multiselect

Comment: Is there a reason of not having `<option>` `value` attribute uniform with `category` values (e.g. `2` vs `cat2`)?

Comment: as you can see of my question the code above works but it just filtering by `ID`

Comment: yeah That's right.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you can use [Array.protoype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) to do this exact task.

```js
var array = [
 {id: true, category: "cat1", name: "test1"},
 {id: true, category: "cat2", name: "test2"},
 {id: true, category: "cat3", name: "test3"},
 {id: true, category: "cat4", name: "test4"},
 {id: true, category: "cat5", name: "test5"},
]

const getByCateg = (arr, categ) => {
  if (categ === "All") return array;
  return arr.filter((item) => item.category === categ);
}

console.log(getByCateg(array, "All"), getByCateg(array, "cat2"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this is not what I want.